# Dolphin KDE like column design for Nautilus or an alternative file browser

Tags: nautilus, kubuntu, dolphin

I'm now an Ubuntu user for several years but a friend of mine has Kubuntu installed and although I'm no fan of KDE i really liked the file Browser "Dolphin". Especially the Mac OSX like "columns design" with the preview at the right side. Like here http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/7531/screenshotlibevent004do.png.

Are there any simple solutions to get this design in nautilus - my search wasn't very productive till now. Usually there is no alternative to installing a new file broswer, but I'm not sure if its worth it.

Does anybody use Dolphin or anything similar under Ubuntu and could share some thoughts?

Greets.

Comment: Unfortunately, KDE team recently had to drop this view from Dolphin also. I hope it's temporary, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hack for thunar, that does this. http://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/thunar-dev/2005-March/000151.html, haven't found anything for nautilus. Download the file in the link, then un archive it to get the folder thunar-ui-prototype-with-colums-view, open the folder, find `Main.py` and right click on it >go to properties >Permissions >select "Allow this file to run as a program"  >Then close out and double click `Main.py` this will run thunar with the column view, granted it's buggy, but I think this layout is incredebly useful, and wonder why other viewers don't have the option.[image]

Also There is Marlin, but it is in Alpha stage(expermintal), but it has the view, and works better than the thunar hack. http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/elementary-file-browser-marlin-is-now.html

To install put each line in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install marlin
```

[image]